# Cannot communicate with Native messaging host (firefox)

Tags: firefox-addon

So, the basic workflow for using a native messaging host is

1. We have to add the registry key to the current user or the local machine and specify the value as the path to the application manifest.
2. Specify the path in the manifest as the executable file (either an exe file or py file)
3. Communicate with the extension and *voila*!

So, my problem is in the first step. I've done the implementation on **Chrome** and it works seamlessly, but when it comes to **Firefox**, I'm not able to communicate with the host. My intuition is that it has something to do with the registry key adding, since I've given the same exe file that was working with Chrome to send back the message. Does anyone know what exactly we need to add to the registry to make it work with Firefox?

**EDIT :** (Adding the files I'm using)

Native messaging host manifest file (com.mozilla.firefox.example.echo-win.json)

```
{
"name": "com.mozilla.firefox.example.echo",
"description": "FireFox Native Messaging API Example Host",
"path": "<path to exe file>",
"type": "stdio",
"allowed_extensions": ["moz-extension://<Internal UUID>/"]
}
```

Extension Manifest file (manifest.json)

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": <name>,    
    "version": "1.0",    
    "description": <description>,    
    "permissions": ["activeTab",  "storage", "nativeMessaging"],    
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },    
    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "examplelol@example.com",
            "strict_min_version": "50.0"
        }
    },    
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://localhost/*"],
        "js":["content.js"]}],    
    "icons": {
        <default icon paths and sizes>
    },
}
```

Registry command I'm using for the native messaging host is

```
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\NativeMessagingHosts\com.mozilla.firefox.example.echo" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0com.mozilla.firefox.example.echo-win.json" /f
```

Comment: Please, show some of your relevant code and error logs, so people could actually help you. Otherwise it's difficult to help you effectively, because it's **guessing**.

Comment: There. I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

The default value of 
`HKLM  SOFTWARE\Mozilla\NativeMessagingHosts\com.mozilla.firefox.example.echo`
should have the value of the full path to the com.mozilla.firefox.example.echo-win.json file. So your reg command seems right.

Possibly also your format here was incorrect - just the ID as far as we use, not the other moz ext formatting.
`"allowed_extensions": ["<Internal UUID>","ID2"]`